# Smallest but fastest computer?

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards, pc

I'm looking for a super small computer that can have:
64gb DDR4 ram
3TB SSD or NVME or something smaller(physical size)
Super fast processor, better than an intel i7 chip or smaller.
And a super small but powerful graphics card allowing 8k video to a VR headset.

The size of this computer has to be the size of an iphone SX MAX or three of them put together front to back.

Price doesn't matter.

Comment: [AFAIK there's only one 8K headset](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ne0cmvl8GqM) and it's... okay. In addition, most ultra SFF PCs max out at 32GB; are you sure you need 64GB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A product like this is non-existent.

Today's component sizes are way bigger than this, so it is not possible to fit those specs into such a small thing.